# Difference between "run into", "come upon" and "come across"

Tags: word-choice, differences, phrasal-verbs

These phrasal verbs have a similar meaning (please correct me if not):

- run into
- come across
- come upon

Are there any nuances to choose between them? For example, I might be wrong but I mostly see *run into* used for meeting a *person* unexpectedly.

**Update:**
My understanding of responses so far:

- *come upon* is not very common any more
- *run into* is the most frequently used one
- *run into* might or might not have a negative connotation (No consensus as I see it)

Perhaps working on some concrete sentences might give a better result. For example, which one would you use for (in parentheses are my first thoughts):

- Unexpectedly meeting a dangerously fierce pack of dogs on the street (run into)
- Unexpectedly meeting a very beautiful girl whom you don't know on the street (come across)
- Unexpectedly finding a book that you had lost (come across)
- Unexpectedly finding a grammar mistake in a blog that you'd love to point out (come across)
- ...

Maybe I should've mentioned *stumble upon* too. 
By the way, sorry about the length of the post. I had to expand it to clarify the context.

Comment: You might like to note that *"to come upon"* has [massively declined](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+came+upon%2Che+came+upon&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) over the past century. I would say by now it's effectively at least "dated" for most people.

Comment: I agree that it's less common than it was, but I don't think it sounds dated.

Comment: Hm, then I'll wait for a possible consensus.

Comment: The length of your question is not a problem; no need to apologize.  We get a lot of very short questions that don't provide enough context, and I wish more people would add the kinds of examples and details that you did.

Comment: It's weird to hear these phrases in the present tense.  I think of them almost exclusively in the past tense.  ran into, came upon, came across.  Maybe the past present as well, "we then come across a skeleton"

Comment: There is also *to chance upon*, which might be poetic or even slightly archaic, but doesn’t sound too bad. It is unambiguously an unexpected event. I like it better than *to come upon*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my experinece you *run into* people and trouble:

> I ran into Betty at the store today.  I haven't seen her since college!
>   I ran into your co-worker Bob today.
>   Sorry I'm late; I ran into heavy traffic.

You *come across* objects:

> I was cleaning up the kitchen and came across that phone bill you lost.
>   I was looking up (something) in the encylopedia and came across this interesting tidbit.

I'm not sure I'd use either when talking about a grammar error in a blog; I'd be more likely to say I *found* or *noticed* it.  I don't know why that is.

Answer (score 7):

When you [run into](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=14402083) something, it's likely to be metaphorical and those metaphorical encounters are usually negative. The most common noun collocates are: *problem, trouble, wall, difficulty, opposition, resistance,* and *roadblock*. It also commonly means meeting a person unexpectedly.

The next item, *[come upon](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=14402096)*, is far less common than *run into* and is usually used when have physically moved into a situation or location. The most common noun collocates are: *scene, sight,* and *accident.* And the most common adverbs are *suddenly* and *finally,* which are almost equally frequent, suggesting this is used both when you're searching and when you're not.

About as frequent as *come upon* is *[come across](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=14402115),* the most common meaning of which is that you've physically travelled across something (e.g., a bridge), and there's also the meaning of how you are perceived (i.e., *come across as*), but in the sense suggested by this group of finding vocabulary, usually it's something your find while reading. Relevant collocations are: *article, reference,* and *script.*

Comment: +1 There's everything that answers the question and more.

Comment: I would argue that "run into" is only usually negative when the object of the sentence is _not_ a person.  Also that "come across" could be more broadly related to searching of any kind, not limited to reading.

Comment: @Sam, I certainly agree. These are just tendencies, which is why I put *usually* and *likely.*

Comment: So I understand I could use "run into" to say "I unexpectedly met a pack of fierce dogs on the street.". And what about "I unexpectedly met a very beautiful girl on the street."? (Assuming I'm a guy and, well, into girls:) )

Comment: -1 for the first paragraph. I just checked the first few pages of Ngram hits for *"I ran into"*, 1990-1999. Well over half were positive/neutral contexts involving a chance meeting with another person. Most of the rest were simply literal (I entered some place at a run), and I didn't notice a single instance of anything like "running into trouble" - that sense is obviously not at all unusual, but it's **nowhere near the most likely**.

Comment: @henginy, I would think that you'd only use "ran into" in reference to a fierce pack of dogs if there had been some hint as to the potential for danger. "Came across" seems to me, much more apt in that instance. Running into a person, also typically implies knowing the person in question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I said it was likely, not "the most likely." I've edited the post to clarify that the negative refers to the metaphorical objects, not all objects.

Comment: @Brett Reynolds: To be honest, I don't see how *"it's likely"* can mean anything other than *"more probable than any other alternative"* in any context. I certainly can't interpret your first sentence as compatible with my understanding that *running into [problems]* is in fact at least the **third most likely** meaning. I'd also point out that it's the *"running into"* that's "metaphorical", not the thing encountered (in that the usage normally means "met by chance", not "physically collided with").

Comment: FF's research apparently contradicts the claim "and those metaphors are usually negative". Brett, your move.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: All I can say is that that's not how I understand *likely.* There are many different types of things you can run into. Things like problems form a large part of that. You're right, though, that it's the running into that is metaphorical and not the objects. Responding too quickly.

Comment: The LDOCE lists as its first sense for the phrasal verb *run into* (under run http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/run_1 ) "to start to experience a difficult or unpleasant situation." Meeting a person is listed as sense #4, and the LDOCE lists its senses in frequency order.

Comment: @Brett Reynolds: I'm not claiming that somehow I instinctively "know" which usage is actually more common. Like you, I'm just one person, so my experience is limited to what I hear/use most - and I certainly wouldn't trust myself to have counted and weighed all the different usages I personally have known. But unless someone gives me a good reason *not* to trust it, I think when a straw poll of the first 50-100 instances in Google Books strongly points in one direction, I should be inclined to go with it. That's all I've done here.

Comment: The COCA collocations and the entry from the LDOCE aren't good reasons? Also, consider that the COCA is a more balanced corpus than NGrams (which is obviously much larger).

Comment: ...just a theory, but I think on average ELU contributors have a relatively high proportion of "office workers" (particularly, computer specialists). It may well be that in their working environment, such people are more likely than most to find themselves explaining to the boss that they've *"run into problems"* (personally, I'd rather try and blame some troublesome situation on those "unexpected" problems, rather than simply say *"Sorry, boss, I just messed up!"* :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with LDOCE, but I note that *"run into"* for *"meet someone by chance"* is listed as **informal**. In the circumstances, it seems [most!] likely to me that they list "informal" usages *after* whatever they don't consider to be such. Though why they think that usage is informal, whereas a *"bill running into hundreds of pounds"* isn't, Lord only knows.

Comment: I've added the sense of meeting people. Does this seem reasonable?

Answer (score 4):

They all mean "to encounter unexpectedly", but are used in different contexts:

- *Run into* means to encounter someone (or something) during your normal course of events, often while physically traveling: *I **ran into** Sally at the supermarket.*
- *Come across* means to find something (or someone) when you were not looking for him/her/it: *I was cleaning out the garage when I **came across** my high school yearbook.*

Note that the phrase "come across" has a completely different sense where it also means "to be understood (perhaps wrongly)": *I tried to tell her I was worried about her, but I'm afraid I **came across** as critical instead of concerned.*

- *Come upon* means to find a thing or (often) a situation during your course of events, somewhat similar to "run into" except usually referring to inanimate things or situations and without the implicit subcontext of physical travel: *While reading* Paradise Lost *, I **came upon** the most amazing literary passage.* It's often used interchangeably with "come across" (the first sense).

I disagree that "come upon" is now uncommon. It's never been an overly common expression, but I think it's probably used as much now as ever.

Answer (score 3):

The distinctions are very subtle, and while I don't necessarily disagree with Brett, I think he's overstating. To really answer this you might need to study many examples in context.

I think that "run into" tends to be used to describe something you find accidentally when travelling. (Not necessarily to a foreign country or anything like that, it could be across the street.) "Come upon" and "come across" tend to be used when describing something you find while searching for something else or working on something else.

Like, "I was in the grocery store yesterday when I *ran into* my friend Sally." But, "I was searching the closet for my brown shoes when I *came across* some old photographs." You wouldn't normally switch the two. But the differences are subtle and if you did, it would sound only slightly odd.

Of course if you say, "I was driving down the street at 60 mile per hour when I ran into Sally", that means something quite different.

Answer (score 1):

[Come across something](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/come-across-sth#come-across-sth__2)

[Run into somebody](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/run-into-sb#run-into-sb__2)

Answer (score 0):

I will compare "run into" and "come across" in the meaning of "to meet something or someone". Those verbs have multiple meanings. "Come upon" is marked "literary" or "formal" in modern dictionaries.

**run into somebody** *(rather informal)*: meet someone you know by chance. The key word here is "someone you know". In this meaning, it doesn't have any negative connotations:

*I ran into an old neighbour of mine at the garage this afternoon.*

*You rarely run into people you know in London.*

However, "run into something/someone" in the sense of "to crash (your vehicle) into it/them" is obviously bad.

**come across something**: to find something unexpectedly when you are not looking for it but are doing something else, as in:

*Jill came across her son's diary when she was tidying his room one day.*

**come across somebody**: to meet/find someone by chance, when you are not expecting it, as in:

*You must have come across some weird and wonderful people while you were there.*

*I came across an old school friend of mine when I was travelling in Canada.*

*I came across a group of children playing.*

*He's the most unpleasant man I've ever come across.*

*I came across children sleeping under bridges.*

My guess is that you usually run into people you know, whereas you come across people you know or total strangers.

Also notice the following examples where "run into" doesn't sound good or it changes the meaning of a sentence:

*Just recently, I came across a familiar looking gorgeous man on facebook.*

*Was just on a dating website and came across my ex girlfriend on it?*

*Ever notice how you come across somebody once in a while you shouldn't have fucked with?*

*Your [sic!] going to come across a lot of shitty bands, and a lot of shitty people.*

*When you come across your crush, you feel like you are melting and as if you are going to faint.*

With things, it's simple. When you find something by chance, you come across it.

The Oxford Phrasal Verbs Dictionary marks "come across sb/sth" as very common. It doesn't mark "run into" as common.

Sources: the Longman Phrasal Verbs Dictionary, The Oxford Phrasal Verbs Dictionary, the Cambridge Phrasal Verbs Dictionary, the Longman Language Activator, The Oxford Learner's Thesaurus

Comment: I think you should have covered ***to run across***.  It means “To meet or fall in with, typically by chance.”  It is contemporary, with [OED citations from 1846–2006](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/168875#eid265291980), and very close if not identical  to ***run into***. It’s certainly newer than the the older forms like ***come upon*** or the somewhat poetic ***chance upon***. I’m sure you’ve run across it before.

Comment: @tchrist, There's also bump into, stumble across/on/upon, chance on etc.